# Unable to load custom tflite model using Firebase ML Kit

Tags: android, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite, firebase-mlkit

I am integrating object detection using ML kit i am  creating custom tflite model using firebase ML and  follow this doc https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml-kit/android/use-custom-models for loading custom model but getting below error while loading the model

**com.google.firebase.ml.common.FirebaseMLException: Local model load failed with the model options: Local model name:modelname . Remote model name: unspecified.**

```
   private fun configureLocalModelSource() {
        // [START mlkit_local_model_source]
        val localSource = FirebaseLocalModel.Builder("my_local_model") // Assign a name to this model
                .setAssetFilePath("my_model.tflite")
                .build()
        FirebaseModelManager.getInstance().registerLocalModel(localSource)
        // [END mlkit_local_model_source]
    }

    @Throws(FirebaseMLException::class)
    private fun createInterpreter(): FirebaseModelInterpreter? {
        // [START mlkit_create_interpreter]
        val options = FirebaseModelOptions.Builder()
                .setRemoteModelName("my_cloud_model")
                .setLocalModelName("my_local_model")
                .build()
        val interpreter = FirebaseModelInterpreter.getInstance(options)
        // [END mlkit_create_interpreter]

        return interpreter
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure you included the local model with the same name in your build and/or have the remote model with right name exists in your console?

Comment: This issue is fixed by adding  this line in build,gradle aaptOptions {
        noCompress "tflite"
    }